# Passing variables without a form using url

Tags: php, parameter-passing

I have been trying to find information on passing variables without a form using url, but I can't seem to find anythig that pertains to my situation. 
Basically I need to have a page that is hierachical in the sense that you can click one course out of a list, that brings you to a list of sections, and you can click on a section which will bring to a page with the correct information for that one section. I was taught for this situation to use $_SESSION and then to include the variables in the url. My problem is that everytime I click on a course or a section, the information for every single course or section that is a query match is displaying rather than just the information for that one course or section.  This is what I have for each of the pages in hierarchical order (not including the connect portion of the code which works fine anyways). I know this is a ton of code, and a complete mess. I will keep searching out information, and many many thanks in advance for any help.

List of Courses

```
  session_start(); 
$section = $_SESSION['section_id'];
$user_fname = $_SESSION['user_fname'];
$user_lname = $_SESSION['user_lname'];





     $query = "SELECT DISTINCT course_t.course_id, course_name, user_fname, user_lname, section_t.section_id   
               FROM   course_t, authorized_user_t, section_t, teaching_history_t
               WHERE authorized_user_t.authorized_user_id = teaching_history_t.instructor_id
                AND teaching_history_t.section_id = section_t.section_id
                AND section_t.course_id = course_t.course_id";





 $result = @mysql_query($query);



 while ($line1 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {


   echo '<p align = "center"><strong><a href ="section_list.php?section_id='.$line1['section_id'].'&user_fname='.$line1['user_fname'].'&user_lname='.$line1['user_lname'].'">' .$line1['course_id'].':'.$line1['course_name']. '</a></strong><br><br>'; 




     }
```

List of Sections (it is supposed to list a single intructor and then each of the sections they teach under their name)

```
 session_start();

 $section_id = $_REQUEST['section_id'];
 $user_fname = $_REQUEST['user_fname'];
 $user_lname = $_REQUEST['user_lname'];


$course_id = $_SESSION['course_id'];
$course_name = $_SESSION['course_name'];
$section_id = $_SESSION['section_id'];
$semester = $_SESSION['semester'];
$year = $_SESSION['year'];
$course_description = $_SESSION['course_description'];
$SGoal_Description = $_SESSION['SGoal_Description'];
$sobjective_description = $_SESSION['sobjective_description'];
$LObjective_Description = $_SESSION['LObjective_Description'];
$topic_title = $_SESSION['topic_title'];
$topic_description = $_SESSION['topic_description'];
$coursework_title = $_SESSION['coursework_title'];
$coursework_location = $_SESSION['coursework_location'];
$coursework_description = $_SESSION['coursework_description'];



  $query = "SELECT course_t.course_id, course_name, section_t.section_id, semester, year, course_description,
                  SGoal_Description, sobjective_description, LObjective_Description, topic_title, topic_description, coursework_title, 
                  coursework_location, coursework_description, syllabus 
               FROM course_t, section_t, section_goal_section_t, section_goal_t, section_coursework_t,
                 mapped_topic_section_t, mapped_lis_section_t, coursework_t, topic_t, lis_objective_t, section_objective_t
               WHERE course_t.course_id = section_t.course_id
                 AND section_t.section_id = section_goal_section_t.section_id
                 AND section_goal_section_t.sgoal_id = section_goal_t.sgoal_id
                 AND section_goal_section_t.section_id = mapped_lis_section_t.section_id
                 AND mapped_lis_section_t.lobjective_id = lis_objective_t.lobjective_id
                 AND section_t.section_id = mapped_topic_section_t.section_id
                 AND mapped_topic_section_t.topic_id = topic_t.topic_id
                 AND section_t.section_id = section_coursework_t.section_id
                 AND mapped_lis_section_t.sobjective_id = section_objective_t.sobjective_id
                 AND section_coursework_t.coursework_id = coursework_t.coursework_id"; 


   $result = @mysql_query($query);

         while ($line1 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {


   echo '<ul align = "center"<strong>' .'Instructor'. ':' ."$user_fname". "$user_lname".'<li align = "center">
   <a href ="course_section.php?course_id='.$line1['course_id'].'&course_name='.$line1['course_name'].'&section_id='.$line1['section_id'].'
     &semester='.$line1['semester'].'&year='.$line1['year'].'&course_description='.$line1['course_description'].'
     &SGoal_Description='.$line1['SGoal_Description'].'&sobjective_description='.$line1['sobjective_description'].'
     &LObjective_Description='.$line1['LObjective_Description'].'&topic_title='.$line1['topic_title'].'
     &topic_description='.$line1['topic_description'].'&coursework_title='.$line1['coursework_title'].'
     &coursework_location='.$line1['coursework_location'].'&coursework_description='.$line1['coursework_description'].'">'.$line1['section_id'].'</a></strong><br><br>'; 


  }
```

Section Information (should display information for the section that is clicked on)

```
   session_start();

       $topic_description = $SESSION['topic_description'];
       $coursework_description = $SESSION['coursework_description'];

         $course_id = $_REQUEST['course_id'];
         $course_name = $_REQUEST['course_name'];
         $section_id = $_REQUEST['section_id'];
         $semester = $_REQUEST['semester'];
         $year = $_REQUEST['year'];
         $course_description = $_REQUEST['course_description'];
         $SGoal_Description = $_REQUEST['SGoal_Description'];
         $sobjective_description = $_REQUEST['sobjective_description'];
         $LObjective_Description = $_REQUEST['LObjective_Description'];
         $topic_title = $_REQUEST['topic_title'];
         $topic_description = $_REQUEST['topic_description'];
         $coursework_title = $_REQUEST['coursework_title'];
         $coursework_location = $_REQUEST['coursework_location'];
         $coursework_description = $_REQUEST['coursework_description'];



    echo '<div align  = "right">';   

     echo '<a href="section_list.php">Return to List of Sections</a>';

        echo '</div>';


    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT course_t.course_id, course_name, section_t.section_id, semester, year, course_description,
                  SGoal_Description, sobjective_description, LObjective_Description, topic_title, topic_description, coursework_title, 
                  coursework_location, coursework_description, syllabus 
                FROM course_t, section_t, section_goal_section_t, section_goal_t, section_coursework_t,
                 mapped_topic_section_t, mapped_lis_section_t, coursework_t, topic_t, lis_objective_t, section_objective_t
               WHERE course_t.course_id = section_t.course_id
                 AND section_t.section_id = section_goal_section_t.section_id
                 AND section_goal_section_t.sgoal_id = section_goal_t.sgoal_id
                 AND section_goal_section_t.section_id = mapped_lis_section_t.section_id
                 AND mapped_lis_section_t.lobjective_id = lis_objective_t.lobjective_id
                 AND section_t.section_id = mapped_topic_section_t.section_id
                 AND mapped_topic_section_t.topic_id = topic_t.topic_id
                 AND section_t.section_id = section_coursework_t.section_id
                 AND mapped_lis_section_t.sobjective_id = section_objective_t.sobjective_id
                 AND section_coursework_t.coursework_id = coursework_t.coursework_id"; 

       $result = @mysql_query($query);


    while ($line1 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))   {


      echo '<p align = "center"><strong>' .$line1['course_id'].':'.' '.$line1['course_name']. '</strong><br><br>';

       echo '<p align = "center"><strong>' .$line1['section_id'].':'.' '.$line1['semester'].'/'.$line1['year']. '</strong><br><br>';

       echo '<p align = "left"><strong>' .$line1['course_description'].'</strong><br><br><br><br>';




  echo '<div align  = "left">';           

       echo '<ul align = "left"><strong>Section Goals:</strong></ul><li align = "left">' .$line1['SGoal_Description']. '</li>';

       echo '<ul align = "left"><strong>Section Objectives:</strong></ul><li align = "left">' .$line1['sobjective_description']. '</li>';

       echo '<ul align = "left"><strong>Mapped Objectives:</strong></ul><li align = "left">' .$line1['LObjective_Description']. '</li>';

       echo '<ul align = "left"><strong>'.'Topic'.':'.' '.$line1['topic_title']. '</strong></ul>
         <li align = "left"><a href = "topic_description.php?topic_description= '.$line1['topic_description'].'"target="_blank">Click for Topic Description</a>';

       echo '<ul align = "left"><strong>'.'Coursework'.':'.' '.$line1['coursework_title']. '</strong></ul>
         <li align = "left"><a href = "coursework_description.php?coursework_description= '.$line1['coursework_description'].'"target="_blank">Click for Coursework Description</a>';




  }
```

Comment: i don't see a need for sessions just pass the var in the url

Comment: Your codes are messy. Really messy.

Comment: @dagon that's his problem he doesnt know that.

Comment: well that's the point of the comment - to inform him.

Comment: if I just pass the variable in the URL without $_Session, it is still returning all of the information on one page rather than the information for just the one course section

Comment: @user1350252 and where in all that code is that bit, your not making it easy to help you.

Comment: none of your queries are using any variables, so i'm not sure what you expect.

Comment: Everyone is saying to not use $_SESSION variables, so I removed them from my code, but it is still not working. I'm not sure what you mean by the query not using variables. What needs to be changed?

Comment: yes but you have to use something? how else do you tell the queries what to return?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sessions, just include it in the url ex: example.com/index.php?example=true. If you use $_GET['example'] it will have the value `'true'`.

Comment: So don't use sessions at all? Replace them with $_GET?

Comment: Correct, but make sure you keep the same variables for each page, ex: redirect to index.php using: `header ("location: index.php?" . $_SERVER['query_string'])` This will keep the same query string for all the redirect pages. Make sure you do this for links also, ex: `<a href="index.php?" . $_SERVER['query_string'] . ">Link</a>`